# Merging two datasets based on multiple criteria

Tags: merge, excel-formula, excel-2010

I know similar questions have been asked here numerous times but I have a specific problem thats why I am posting it here.

I have two datasets in excel that I wish to merge. examples on the web are for matching one variable (ID) in two files and return the adjacent value. In my case, I need to match two variables (ID and corresponding year) and then return the adjacent value.

To elaborate, I have two files: file A, with countrycode, years, variable X and Y. I also have file B, with countrycode, years, variables W and Z. I want to merge these two files so that countrycode and years combination matches in two files and add the two new variables to file A from file B. So my new file A will have variables XYW and Z, all correctly matched for their relative countrycodes and years. I hope my explanation makes sense. Please help me how to do it..

Comment: It might be helpful to provide an example input (both data sets) and output (the one data set)

Comment: Also - have you tried a VLOOKUP?

Comment: A general approach to match multiple columns is to first concatenate them (using a delimiter if required to produce unique results) and then do the lookup on the column that contains the concatenated (multiple criteria) result.

Comment: Ma3x thank you for your responses. I have solved the problem. I will post answer below.

@Skram, can you please give me a link to a guide for how to post a table in questions? I tried to find it but failed. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the question using following formula..

=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$BC,MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$B:$B,0),MATCH($D2,Sheet1!$1:$1,0))

this is what it does..

**=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$BC** this part defines are area in which excel looks for the corresponding values

**MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$B:$B,0)** this part looks for the country code in my example

and

**MATCH($D2,Sheet1!$1:$1,0))** this part looks for the years.